# How to break Crosstab according to Column

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a crosstab data where I need to generate separate crosstabs according to the first field in the column group.

I tried with groups and put the crosstab in group footer and it is failing.I think it works only in summary band

```
error : crosstab is failing to increment.
```

Is there any way to break the crosstab into down after rendering the elements in the first column group?

Like this:

```
    column group1{rowdata} break into down column 
    column group 2{rowdata}...
```

Comment: If you place the crosstab in the group footer, make sure you set resetType="Group" resetGroup="GroupName" for the crosstab dataset.

Comment: Thanks alot  .it works!!